# Access Overloaded operators from Clojure

Tags: c#, clojure

I have a class that exposes a list of data by overloading the index operator (see below).  Can I access this from clojure?

```
double this[int index] { get; }
```

Comment: Show us code, it is hard to help without any clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(let [q (|System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]|.)] 
  (.Add q 1) 
  (.get_Item q 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any thing about C# programming language but the concept should be the same when you call Java code from Clojure.

To call instance method:

```
(.methodName objectInstance params...)
```

To call static method (assuming C# has static methods):

```
(ClassName/staticMethod params...)
```

Comment: Why provide an answer when you are admittedly clueless about the topic? Chances are OP tried basic interop syntax already.

Comment: @vemv Sorry but should I ask for your permission to post here?